# I need help for this Volley requestQue, always crashes in actual device

Tags: java, android

the error is pointing to this requestQueue.add(stringRequest). Everytime i run this app in actual device, it crashes. i declared my Volley requestQue right after service declaration.

```
public class SmsService extends Service {

        public RequestQueue requestQueue;
        public StringRequest stringRequest;


stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, smsurl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("Debug", response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "No Internet Connection!!");

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("email",email);
                    hashMap.put("targetname",targetname);
                    hashMap.put("smstype",smstype);
                    hashMap.put("phone",phone);
                    hashMap.put("contactname",contactname);
                    hashMap.put("body",body);
                    hashMap.put("date",date);

                    return hashMap;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Where do you create your `requestQueue`??

Comment: `RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);` try this

Comment: @AmitBasliyal i tried RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  and still i got the same error.

Comment: @petey i edited my post, can you tell me where is the right place to declare/create my requestQue? Thanks

Comment: @AmitBasliyal thank you for your answer. its working now.

Comment: public void saveSmsData(String... params){
  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
}